# cfs display uploaded files in client side

Tags: meteor

My code:
**server/app.js**

```
var imageLargeStore = new FS.Store.S3("imagesLarge", {
  accessKeyId: "xxxx", 
  secretAccessKey: "xxx", 
  bucket: "profile-thumbs", 
  transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
    gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('250', '250').stream().pipe(writeStream)
  }
});
var imageSmallStore = new FS.Store.S3("imagesSmall", {
  accessKeyId: "xxxx", 
  secretAccessKey: "xxx",
  bucket: "profile-thumbs",
  transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
    gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('80', '80').stream().pipe(writeStream)
  }
});


thumbs = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [imageLargeStore,imageSmallStore]
});
Meteor.publish("images", function() {
  return thumbs.find();
});
thumbs.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
  },
  update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
  },
  download:function(){
    return true;
  }
});
```

**client/app.js**

```
var imageLargeStore = new FS.Store.S3("imagesLarge");
var imageSmallStore = new FS.Store.S3("imagesSmall");
thumbs = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [imageLargeStore,imageSmallStore],
  filter: {
    allow: {
      contentTypes: ['image/*']
    }
  }
})
```

uploading is working fine and I can see the image in aws

```
thumbs.insert(res,function(err,fileobj){
      console.log(fileobj);
    })
```

I published and subscribed to all the collection in client

I tried to display images but they are not showing

```
{{#each images}}
    <div>
       <a href="{{this.url}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{this.url store='imageSmallStore' uploading='/amazon.png' storing='/angjs.jpg'}}" alt="" class="thumbnail" /></a>
                </div>

 {{/each}}

images:function(){
  return thumbs.find({});
}
```

But Images are not showing, instead of storing image(angjs.jpg) is showing.

when I inspect the element I can see the url like

but Image is not showing,what is the issue with my code?

[image]

I'm getting this error when I try to open Image in aws console

Comment: if you put this what you get? `<a href="{{this.url}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{this.url store='imageSmallStore' }}" alt="" class="thumbnail" /></a>`

Comment: @Ethaan, no that's not working

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also running into something similar

Answer (score 0):

I think what happens is you are defining allow rules for the collection but only on the server. The client also needs access to the `download` property of the collection to be able to access the file's data (not the actual image)

The official documentation kind's of explain this https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#security